# How to import C++ libraries in Xcode?

Tags: c++, xcode, macos

I'm using Xcode for developing a simple app. I need a library called cURL, for manage simple connection methods, but I really dunno how to import this library in Xcode. I am programming in C++, and I know that isn't very a good idea program that on a Mac, but I haven't got other options. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why isn't C++ a good idea on the Mac?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`libcurl` is a standard library on Mac OS X - headers are in `/usr/include/curl` and libraries are in `/usr/lib` as you might expect.

You can either just add the relevant header(s) and library(ies) to your project explicitly (makes looking stuff up easier and avoids having to set build flags), or you can do it the *old skool* way by specifying linker flags in the build settings.